# Como executar solicitação novamente após ter permissão aceita no android?

Tags: java, android

Tenho um botão que ao ser pressionado ele deve abrir o modo de chamada telefônica com um numero dinâmico.

Este método requer a permissão **CALL_PHONE**. E quando é pressionado a primeira vez, abre um dialogo perguntando se autorizo a permissão solicitada. E mesmo que a pessoa aceite, ele não continua a ligação. E eu não tenho como executar o numero novamente, pois é um numero dinâmico e não tem como o aplicativo descobrir qual foi o numero clicado.

Eu coloquei uma função que chama o numero dessa forma: `makeCall("999999 numero dinâmico aqui");`

Segue o meu código para entender melhor:

```
   public void makeCall(String s) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + s));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestForCallPermission();
        } else {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public void requestForCallPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Aqui eu preciso arranjar um modo de executar o makeCall novamente, mas não tenho como saber qual será o numero.
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Como posso passar alguma variável através do **onRequestPermissionsResult** para que o aplicativo saiba qual numero deve ligar?

Comment: Já pensou em salvar o número em uma variável de classe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private String _number;

    public void makeCall(String s) {
        _number = s;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + s));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestForCallPermission();
        } else {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public void requestForCallPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Aqui eu preciso arranjar um modo de executar o makeCall novamente, mas não tenho como saber qual será o numero.
                    makeCall(_number);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado perozzo sua resposta funcionou perfeitamente. Era isso mesmo que eu precisava.

Comment: @FernandoVR Magina! Feliz em ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isAutorizado(){
    return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
private void doCall(){
    if (isAutorizado()){
        //fazer chamada
        makeCall(editextDigitado.getText().toString());
    }else{
        //pedir permissão
        requestForCallPermission();
    }
}

/**
 * Metodo que faz chamada
 * @param s
 */
public void makeCall(String s) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + s));
    startActivity(intent);        
}

public void requestForCallPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            for (int i=0;i<permissions.length;i++) {
                String permissao = permissions[i];
                if (permissao.equals(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)&& grantResults[i]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    makeCall(editextDigitado.getText().toString());
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Essa resposta não serve para mim Weslley, pq não tem nenhum campo de texto na activity, ele puxa o numero através de um banco de dados, onde a requisição é feita apenas uma vez. A resposta do amigo perozzo abaixo foi a mais correta para mim. Mesmo assim obrigado por responder.

Comment: era so por o numero no lugar né, mas ta bom